# unable to connect to oracle11g db using ADODB

Tags: vba, oracle11g, adodb

I am trying to validate data in the oracle DB using ADODB. I installed the Oracle Client x64 bit and configured the environment variables correctly. For some reason, the below code throws `automation error` which is not very helpful to narrow down the problem.

PS: I also tried the same by installing the 32 bit version of the oracle client.

```
Sub test()
    myHost = ""
    Database_Name = ""
    myUsername = ""
    myPassword = ""
    serviceID = ""
    myPort = ""

    strConnectionString = "Driver={Oracle in OraClient11g_home1}; " & _
                            "SERVER=(DESCRIPTION=" & _
                            "(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)" & _
                            "(HOST=" & myHost & ")(PORT=" & myPort & "))" & _
                            "(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=" & serviceID & "))); uid=" & myUsername & ";pwd=" & myPassword & ";"

    Debug.Print strConnectionString
    'Instantiate the Connection object and open a database connection.
    Set cnn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    cnn.Open strConnectionString
    'Above line throws error 


End Sub
```

**Error Message**

*

> Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications
>
> Run-time error '-2147217843 (80040e4d)': Automation error  OK   Help

*

Thought of reaching out to experts support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get that working with **Oracle in OraClient11g_home1** driver. So I installed 32 bit **Microsoft ODBC for Oracle** and got the job done.

```
Set objCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objRec = CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
Dim fieldName, fieldValue
Dim host_name: host_name = ""
Dim service_name: service_name = ""
Dim user_name : user_name = ""
Dim pass : pass = ""
Dim strSQL : strSQL = ""
Dim data_array
data_array = Array("","","")

conStr = "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};Server=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=" & host_name & ")(PORT=1525))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=" & service_name & "))); Uid=" & user_name & ";Pwd=" & pass &";"
objCon.Open conStr      

objRec.Open strSQL, objCon

Set objFields = objRec.Fields
Do Until objRec.EOF
    For intLoop = 0 To (objFields.Count - 1)
        fieldName = objFields.Item(intLoop).Name
        fieldValue = objFields.Item(intLoop).Value          
        If Cstr(fieldValue) = Cstr(data_arr(intLoop)) Then
            Debug.print "Check value of " & fieldName &  " Value of " & fieldName & " in DB " & fieldValue & " is same as application " & data_arr(intLoop)
        Else
            Debug.print "Check value of " & fieldName &  " Value of " & fieldName & " in DB " & fieldValue & " is not same as application " & data_arr(intLoop)
        End If
    Next
    objRec.MoveNext
Loop

objRec.Close
objCon.Close
```